# How to use the euler angles with rotations in "YXZ" ranging from -180 to 180 in a non three.js system into a three.js system

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, euler-angles, spherical-coordinate

I have a 360 image (non three.js) system  that outputs my Euler angles ( pitch (x), yaw (y) and roll (z) ) on rotation as "YXZ" order. The bounds of for example yaw are from [-180 to 180] (a net total of 360).

I want to use these angles to rotate a 3d object in another system which is built on three.js.
On change of values in my system 1, I set my Euler angles to the target vector of the camera object in the second system,
It rotates to an extent, but I feel i'm doing something wrong in terms of bounds or may be some other issue due to my very limited knowledge of three.js

Any help would enhance my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Three.js rotations are in radians, and it looks like the `[-180, 180]` range is in degrees. So you're going to have to convert the rotation values from degrees to radians. You could simply use [MathUtils.degToRad()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.degToRad) to do the conversion for you:

```js
var pitch = xxx; // Get pitch from your other system somehow
object.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(pitch);
```